# Holding and using Romanised names with Diacritics

Tags: geonames

I have two True type font files (Permanent Committee on Geographical Names) PCGNA.TTF AND PCGNTN.TTF.

The romanised diacritics are well read in MS excel.

But when I convert this excel in shp or pgdb feature class, it becomes unreadable.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: how do you convert from excel to shp. by default the associated dbf uses western latin encoding as far as I know. can you use utf-8 encoding?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select encoding for SHP-files.

If it works UTF-8 is the best solution. 
If it doesn't you can experiment with other latin2..9 encodings. 
This should work, but it will show encoding correctly for one of the language/diacritics groups.
So it will work fine within a single country. But you may need more than one shape if there are multiple countries involved.